# Update python library offline

Tags: python, pip

I need to update offline a library in Python.

I have downloaded the library with pip download and then I try to update the library with the command:

```
pip install --no-index --user --find-links /tmp/pip/ --upgrade Werkzeug==0.15.5
```

which gives:

> ```
> Ignoring indexes: https://...
> Collecting Werkzeug==0.15.5
> Installing collected packages: Werkzeug
> Successfully installed Werkzeug-0.11.15
> ```

and then the library stays in the same version!

```
pip freeze | grep Wer
```

> Werkzeug==0.11.15

Any ideas why this happens?

**UPDATE**: After the comment from  @hoefling  I rerun with the -vvv option and this is what I got:

```
pip install --no-index --user --find-links /tmp/pip2/ -vvv  Werkzeug==0.15.5
```

> ```
> Ignoring indexes: https://pypi:pypi@..../simple/
> Collecting Werkzeug==0.15.5
>   0 location(s) to search for versions of Werkzeug:
>   Skipping link /tmp/pip2/werk/ (from -f); not a file
>   Found link file:///tmp/pip2/werk/Werkzeug-0.15.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl,       version:
>   0.15.5
>   Local files found: /tmp/pip2/werk/Werkzeug-0.15.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Using version 0.15.5 (newest of versions: 0.15.5)
> Installing collected packages: Werkzeug
>
> Successfully installed Werkzeug-0.11.15
> Cleaning up...
> ```

Comment: What if you run `pip freeze --user | grep Wer` ?

Comment: I did this but is not installed for my user. It only is shown with pip freeze.

Comment: This might be the problem. What if you omit the `--update` and just install it for the user first?

Comment: Can you rerun the command with `-vvv` added and add the log to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
pip install Werkzeug-0.15.5.tar.gz
```

and the result must be like this:

```
Processing ./Werkzeug-0.15.5.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: Werkzeug
  Running setup.py install for Werkzeug ... done
Successfully installed Werkzeug-0.15.5
```

Comment: I does the same thing. The version of Werkzeug is 0.11.15

Comment: it’s written “Successfully installed...”

Comment: it means it done correctly so you are connected to wrong venv. if i were you i would remove venv and build it again.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour can happen because `pip` by default works with system Python which is located in `/usr/bin/` on Linux. When installing the package, by giving Python `--user` flag your package is installed in your user's version of Python, probably located somewhere in `~/.local/`.

To solve the problem you can install the package to your system Python, which is generally not recommended without `--user` flag. Another option is to use virtual environments and have the distribution that is made specifically for your project. Currently the recommended way is using `venv`.

```sh
$ python -m venv env
$ source env/bin/activate
(env) $ pip install ... (packages you need to install without --user flag)
(env) $ pip freeze 
# should give you the packages you installed
```

This can help you not only with this example, but it can always keep your system Python installation clean and if you mess something up, you will only mess the environment you are having for specific project.